# Validate date in grails domain object.

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm using grails 2.4 and bootstrap date picker.

I'm trying to save and update my dates and validate them. I'm BindingFormat to convert my string to a date object.

```
@BindingFormat('MM/dd/yyyy')
Date expenseDate
```

When I save my date, my validator sees it in the following format.

> E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy

So when I validate the date in my domain validator, I'm using the following code.

```
final static DateFormat DATEFORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat('E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy')

static constraints = {  
    expenseDate validator: {
        try {
            DATEFORMAT.parse(it.toString())
            return true
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return 'invalidDateFormat'
        }
    }
}
```

Now on a new record, everything appears to work properly until I go to modify the record. When I attempt to modify the record, as soon as the page loads I automatically get a validation failure because the format the database is returning is **2016-01-01 00:00:00.0** How do I go about getting the saved and returned date objects to be in the same format so that I can properly validate them?

Comment: Your custom validator doesn't make sense to me.  You are turning a `Date` into a `String` and then passing that String to `DATEFORMAT.parse(String)` and it isn't clear why you would do that.  What is `DATEFORMAT.parse(String)` doing, and why do you want to do that as part of your validation routine?

Comment: All I want to do is make sure that the end user isn't creating dates like 05/22/20166 where a sql exception is thrown.

Comment: Never mind my question about what `DATEFORMAT.parse(String)` does.  I see now that it is a `SimpleDateFormat` object.  I don't think there is any good reason to use the validator you have written.

Comment: "All I want to do is make sure that the end user isn't creating dates like 05/22/20166 where a sql exception is thrown." - I think you are confused about how the data binding works, or how the validation works, because the combination of things you are doing there doesn't make sense.

Comment: It seems like all you are really validating is that the `toString()` method in `Date` is returning a `String` that is the format you expect.

Comment: StackOverflow frowns on conversations in the comment threads.  I suggest you post the question in #questions in our public Slack (http://grails.slack.com) or in our Google Group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/grails-dev-discuss.  If you do one of those, we can get it all cleared up.

Comment: The short answer is that you can deal with the invalid input format at binding time, before validation even happens.  By the time validation happens, the input has already been parsed and bound and if that was successful, then you have a well formed `Date` object.

Comment: Well then there is a bug in the binding because I have it set to @BindingFormat('MM/dd/yyyy') and when you enter the date 05/16/20166 I get the following sql exception. spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Only dates between January 1, 1753 and December 31, 9999 are accepted.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/7eaa412b8e07c563a83512cf66d66536

Comment: That gist demonstrates that it isn't really a bug in the binding.  The binding is deferring to the default behavior of `SimpleDateFormat`. https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9667 is relevant, though I am not sure setting lenient to `false` would change the behavior you are describing.

Comment: If you don't like the behavior of `SimpleDateFormat`, you can register your own `Date` converter as a bean in the Spring application context and the data binder will use your converter so you get to impose any rules you like there.